# How do you display colour to a circle using the togglegroup of a radiobutton

Tags: javafx

I am working through some homework problems before exams and need some clarification as how I set the colour of a circle to display what the user selects from a togglegroup onto the screen. I get an error message and the code works to display the size of the circle but when I add the colour in the picture does not display when i click the create button. The error message I receive is "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid color specification" and can;t find solutions online to the problem

I have attempted the code below and it does not work at all.

```
    HBox circleColour = new HBox();
    circleColour.setSpacing(20);
    Label task7 = new Label("What colour do you want the circle: ");
    RadioButton brown = new RadioButton("Brown ");
    RadioButton cyan = new RadioButton("Cyan ");
    RadioButton grey = new RadioButton("Grey ");

    ToggleGroup fillColour = new ToggleGroup();
    brown.setToggleGroup(fillColour);
    cyan.setToggleGroup(fillColour);
    grey.setToggleGroup(fillColour);


      HBox newC = new HBox();
     layout.setRight(newC);

     click.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            //radius
            double newRadius = Double.parseDouble(circleSize.getText());
            circle = new Circle(newRadius);

            //This does not display
            //fill colour
            RadioButton selectedRB = 
      (RadioButton)fillColour.getSelectedToggle();
            String colour = selectedRB.getText();
            System.out.println(colour);
            Color fc = Color.valueOf(colour);
            circle.setFill(fc);
```

Answer (score 1):

An `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown by [`Color.valueOf(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) when:

> [...] the value specifies an unsupported color name or illegal hexadecimal value

You're using the text of the `RadioButton` in order to determine the needed color. The texts you use are supported color names except for one small problem: *You have a space at the end of each text*. The easy fix is to change:

- `"Brown "` → `"Brown"`
- `"Cyan "` → `"Cyan"`
- `"Grey "` → `"Grey"`

If you have those spaces for a reason, or otherwise don't want to use `Color.valueOf`, then another option is to associate each `RadioButton` with a `Color`. There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Using a `Map<RadioButton, Color>` (or `Map<Toggle, Color>` if you prefer).

   ```
   Map<Toggle, Color> colors = new HashMap<>();

   RadioButton brown = new RadioButton("Brown ");
   colors.put(brown, Color.BROWN);

   // retrieval...
   Color color = colors.get(fillColor.getSelectedToggle());
   ```
2. Setting the [user data](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData(java.lang.Object)) of each `RadioButton` (the `Toggle` interface also declares `setUserData` and `getUserData` methods).

   ```
   RadioButton brown = new RadioButton("Brown ");
   brown.setUserData(Color.BROWN);

   // retrieval...
   Color color = (Color) fillColor.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().
   ```

Using one of these options is preferable. You'll run into problems with using the text of the `RadioButton` when, or if, you internationalize the application.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with slaw although there is another option which he did not add and would require less code change and its to use [`.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) which "Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted." which would look like this

```
RadioButton brown = new RadioButton("Brown ");

Color color = Color.valueOf(brown.getText().trim());
```